# Linux how to pass date command's output as input for a python program as command line argument

Tags: python, linux, pipe, command-line-arguments

I am quite a newbie to Linux. I have a very simple Python script that accepts command line arguments and prints them. Now I just want to pass the `date` command's output as input to this Python script and print it. The Python script looks like this.

```
import sys
print "command line arguments recieved are"
for i in range(0,len(sys.argv)) :
   print sys.argv[i]
```

While running this program in order to pass the `date` command's output to script I just did

```
date | python exmp.py
```

Is this the right way to pass one command's output as input of a program?
My program is not taking input from date command. The output I am getting looks like this

```
command line arguments recieved are
exmp.py
```

I am really unable to find out what wrong thing am I doing. Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Read from standard input. You probably should learn more about pipes.

Comment: or from within python `import time; print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the output of `date` to python you can pipe it (using `|`) or you can pass it as a command line argument.

Consider the following python program:

```
import sys

print "Command line input:"
print sys.argv;

print ""

print "Standard input:"
print sys.stdin.read()
```

You can call this program on the command line with:

```
echo "hmm, this is text" | python test3.py "`date`"
```

When I run the program I get:

```
Command line input:
['test3.py', 'Mon  9 Feb 21:10:00 AEST 2015']

Standard input:
hmm, this is text
```

The left quotes around date specify that `date` should be run and that you don't just mean the text `date`.  The double quotes around date force the output of date to be a single command line argument passed to python.  Experiment with removing the outer quotes, the inner quotes and both.

The command of the left of the `|` symbol is executed first, the result is then passed to the program on the right as standard input.  Instead of `echo` you could use:

```
date | python test3.py
```

If you just want to get the date into python, take a look at some of the built in python modules.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different facilities of the Unix shell.

What you are asking can be done like

```
python exmp.py $(date)
```

or you could change your script to read standard input:

```
date | python -c 'import sys
for line in sys.stdin: print line'
```

The expression `$(date)` performs a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html): the command in the brackets is run, and its output is substituted for the bracket expression.

There is a tool called `xargs` for mixing the two:

```
date | xargs python exmp.py
```